# Is this optimization problem called unconstrained quadratic program?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

\begin{equation}
     \arg\min_{c} \frac{1}{2}c^TAc + f^Tc
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix, $f$ and $c$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can we call this problem an unconstrained quadratic program?

Comment: Sometimes (not that often) when people talk about a QP there is an implicit assumption that it is positive semi definite.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Note that depending on whether or not $A$ is positive semidefinite, the problem might be convex or it might be non-convex.  If it is non-convex, then the minimization is unbounded.